# Use mp4 files from 1 site to anoter site hosted on the same server with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have 2 videos sites on the same server and site 1 is already populated with video files. Its there a way to use the video files via `htaccess` from site 1 to site 2 without copying all the video files?

```
site1.com/media/video.mp4

site2.com/media/video.mp4
```

Comment: Do you want to rewrite *all* videos or just the ones that cannot be found on site2.com (yet)?

Comment: Yes i need to rewrite all videos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like the this on `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?media/(.*)$ http://www.site2.com/media/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or simply:

```
Redirect 301 /media http://www.site2.com/media
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for the videos that cannot be found on site2.com ?